# Cloud Optimized vs Cloud Native

Tags: cloud

While trying to have a better understanding on Cloud Native applications, I came across this term Cloud Optimized. Can someone help me with the difference between Cloud Optimized vs Cloud Native ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloud optimization deals about how an application migrated to cloud or developed and hosted there goes through a process of optimization to deliver more value, cuts costs, standardizes things.

Initially once migrated or hosted in cloud there will be less clarity on cloud computing resources used due to the fact that the capacity planning was based on some calculations and previous experiences.

Then after a period of time after observation and analysing monitoring logs etc unused resources will be removed, security policies will be reviewed and updated, better automation and devops practices will come into place and consolidation will happen. Once your processes are standardized for e.g high availability, scaling , data lifecycle patterns would have been identified and standardized.

With a well referenced architecture for cloud, proper security policies , proactive identification of inefficient usage Full transparency to cloud cost, usage, performance, availability and security would have been achieved marking an optimized state.

Cloud native application architecture targets building modern SaaS applications following the [12 factors](http://12factor.net/), microservices architecture with self service agile infrastructure offering an API based colloborative and anti fragile system.

Comment: http://www.gartner.com/webinar/3274118/player?commId=200333&channelId=5502&srcId=1-3478922244  this Gartner webinar talked about 3 categories, 'Cloud Hosted vs Cloud Optimized vs Cloud Native'. Going by your explanation, if i move a traditional application to Cloud without any modification, then it is Cloud Hosted. If i make changes to application like you mentioned then it becomes Cloud Optimized and finally if i architect and build the application for Cloud from ground-up then it becomes Cloud Native, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes that sounds right. Again the terms have slight overlap and may vary slightly on a case to case basis.